# Fail on admin_enqueue_scripts when I try it to upload a CSS file to my WordPress Plugin

Tags: plugins, hooks, plugins-url

I currently doing a WordPress Plugin and I am successful when I try to put CSS or JavaScript on the frontend but I don't know on where I fail when I trying to do the same on backend side, this is my code:

```
function my_function($hook) {
    global $post;
    if($hook == 'post-new.php' || $hook == 'post.php') {
        if($post->post_type == 'post_type_name') {
            wp_enqueue_style('adminCSS', plugins_url('../assets/css/admin.css', __FILE__) );
        }
        
    }
    
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scrips', 'my_function');
```

As you see on my code I only want the CSS file on the plugin's post type side, that's why I do all the stuff with the $hook and the post type.
Can you tell me what error I made there?

Comment: I’m pretty sure you can’t use `../` to go up a directory. That path is just added to the end of the URL, so it won’t work.

Comment: Are you getting a 404 error in the console ?  aka 'File not found`  ?  I tried your code minus your assets path and it is working just fine .

Comment: If your `assets` folder is inside your plugin directory then there is no need to use `../` ( two dots ) but should use `./`(single dot ) instead . If it is not in the plugin directory then you shouldn't use `plugins_url`